# Is there an IRC channel for this Ubuntu community where I can get help and talk to people?

Tags: irc

I'm wondering if there's any IRC channel for Ubuntu where I can talk with other people if I need any help? Also, I'm pretty excited for linux and Ubuntu. I had used Kali Linux in virtual machine before but had never used a Linux OS as my system's operating system.

Anyway, I will like to know if there's any such kind of thing. :)

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 btw. Downloaded and installed it yesterday.

Comment: Are you looking for the [Ask Ubuntu chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many IRC channels, a full list can be found at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList

The main channel is #ubuntu on irc.freenode.net

Answer (score 0):

yes there is , you can visit irc.freenode.net with #Ubuntu.

plus you can try to visit the contact us.

best regards.